# Charge board timer conditions/disabling - mcp73213

Tags: battery-charging, charger

[Datasheet for MCP](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/22190b.pdf)

The MCP73213 has a built in timer.  In the datasheet it states the typical timer elapsed values are 0(disabled) 4, 6, and 8 hours.  The conditions column is empty.

I need to disable this timer, or at least set it to 8 hours (or max allowed time).  Is there any way to?  I have contacted Microchip support with no response.  Has anyone had success with their support?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Table 1 in the data sheet gives you all the options for the device configuration:

[image]

The subtle clue in this table is the words "Factory Preset Options".

The timers, voltages, output status - in fact everything configurable - is configured at the factory, not by you.

When you purchase the chip you specify the settings you require, and they configure it for you (in reality they will probably have pre-configured chips to cover all the option combinations).

It then goes on to say you should contact your local rep to get samples, and that samples come always configured for 6 hour timer.